# Get author image for posts in loop on custom type posts page

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I am archiving all the posts from particular custom post type on a page using the following code.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: List-all-shorts
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="all-shorts-container">
<h2>Shorts</h2>
<?php 
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$author = the_author();
  $custom_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'news',
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'author' => $author
    );
  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); ?>
<?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="single-shorts-container">
      <article class="short-box">
        <div class="short-content">
       <div class="short-meta-box">
        <div class="short-author-meta-img"> <?php   the_author_image();     
        ?>
       </div>
          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <footer class="short-rating-footer">
                <?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
    </footer>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->
 <!-- pagination here -->
    <?php
      if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
        custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
      }
    ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The above code displays all the posts as I wanted. I am trying to show author image of all the individual posts accordingly. I tried using

```
<?php the_author(); ?> and <?php  echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' ); ?>
```

and many other things. But I am getting the image of the author of the page. I am quite not sure where I went wrong.

Also, I am able to get the author name and author profile link for the posts. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use a page to get the custom post type posts? If you have a custom post type cars you should create a cars-archive.php as template and the url /cars should show your custom post type cars. You created a page to show the post type that's possible but not the common way.

So copy your code  into yourposttype-archive.php and go after that to yoursiteurl.com/yourposttype that should work.

Comment: will the same code work?

Comment: I think it does, if not let me know

Comment: you mean archive-posttype.php? I tried it. it is not working.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates  for more info . In the cars example you make a loop template archive-cars.php not archive-posttype.php what is your post type name?

Comment: here, my post type name is news. and the page's name is Shorts.

Comment: Create a archive-news.php en copy past your code in that template delete your page shorts en open yoursite.com/news that should work. If the url shows nothing you have to change your permalinks to ?page= structure and than back to the original friendly urls hope that's the solution for you